# python file.exists not working in program but in python console(interactive)

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

Got a simple program to clone a remote git repo and check if few file/directories exist.

It is simply as , under a directory, after completing git clone, go inside that new directory(created by git clone) and look for existence of few file/directory, issue here is if i check thro program it says such file/directory not found but if it do ls(in terminal) or go to python console check existence using os.path.exists it exists

```
#!/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
base_dir='/something'
os.chdir(base_dir)
subprocess.Popen(["git clone github.com/something.git"],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
os.chdir(something)
some_file=base_dir+"/"+something+"/"+"good_directory/subdirectory/good_file"
if os.path.exists(some_file):
    print("nice")
else:
    print("oh file doesnt exist!")


try:
    shutil.rmtree(something)
except OSError:
     pass
```

When i run this program, it says "good_file" doesnt exist(it exists!) BUT when i run in interactive mode, it shows as TRUE.
Am sure am missing something, please help me.

Comment: Your example code seems to use a variable `something` that you don't show the definition of. You also have `base_dir` which is the string `"/something"`, but it's not clear how they're related. Can you perhaps make a [mcve] (preferably one that doesn't do a git checkout)?

Comment: I gave example, sorry if it is not clear, it is simply as , under a directory, after completing git clone, go inside that new directory(created by git clone) and look for existence of few file/directory, issue here is if i check thro program it says such file/directory not found but if it do ls(in terminal) or go to python console check existence using os.path.exists it exists